# How to model in JPA a "default selection" from a One-to-Many Relationship

Tags: java, jpa, database-design, one-to-many, one-to-one

I have a data model in which a `Person` may be known by one or more `Name`s (such as the case of a woman who has changed her name after marriage).  The model distinguishes the single `Name` that is being actively used.

The general relationship between `Person` and `Name` is modeled as usual: a bidirectional @OneToMany relationship in the `Person` entity and the corresponding @ManyToOne relationship in the `Name` entity classes.

To specify the "active or primary name" I have thought that I could model this as a unidirectional @OneToOne relationship from `Person` to `Name`.  The mappings in the entity classes would look like this:

```
public class Person {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.Identity)
    private Long pers_id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "name_id", nullable = false)
    private Name uniPrimaryName;

        :
        :

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owningSidePerson", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Name> mappedSideNames;

        :
        :
}
```

And the `Name` entity class:

```
public class Name

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.Identity)
    private Long name_id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinTable (name = "XREF_NAMES_PERSON",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "name_id", nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pers_id", nullable = false))
    private Person owningSidePerson;

        :
        :
}
```

The advantage of this model is that it lets me access the primary `Name` as a simple property access from `Person`.  It should also be easier to maintain.  The downside relates to serializing `Person` entities that have circular references, but this problem is present whether the unidirectional relationship is present or not.

An alternative model would be to add an `active` boolean attribute to the `Name` entity and use it to indicate which entity in the relationship was the active one.  The downsides are that maintaining the attribute would be less straightforward and obtaining the active `Name` would require a separate database query.

Before I invested time in this design, I wanted to ask if anyone has tried this before.  I have concerns about an object model which uses an entity object that would be present in a unidirectional and a bidirectional relationship at the same time.

Comment: I have used your first idea. The main problem with it is the circular dependency: you can't delete a person because it's referenced by its names, and you can't delete a name because it's referenced by a person. But if you make sure to do the things in the right order and flush, or if you use deferred constraints, it can work fine.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to just leave the person's relationship to name (mappedSideNames) and delete the relationship mapped by uniPrimaryName attribute to identify whether the name is primary or not u can create a named query  for this purpose, but you will have to create a way to differentiate the primary names as you quoted by setting a flag.

Comment: Yes, as was discussed in the question, a way to accomplish this would be by creating, say, a boolean attribute in the `Name` entity to designate the primary name.  Maintaining this attribute would not be straightforward.  The primary name would also be a frequently accessed property.  Having to execute a separate query in order to obtain it or using application logic to find it doesn't seem to be an optimal solution